# How to apply custom font to all Labels, UITextFields and UIButtons in entire framework?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, fonts, ios-frameworks

I am working on creating my own framework with common screens and functions. I am stuck at achieving the following:

- I have 3 screens inside the framework and which are having `UILabel` and `UITextField`.
- I want to apply the font to all `UILabel` and `UITextField` inside the framework which is used throughout the application.

> Example: If I am using "Kingthings_Trypewriter_2.ttf" in my
>   application then by writing this line should change the font of all
>   respective `UILabels` and `UITextFields`.

```
UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "Kingthings_Trypewriter_2", size: 20)
UITextView.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "Kingthings_Trypewriter_2", size: 20)
```

- Still, by using the above code it is working for labels and UITextFields of application but not with labels and UITextFields of **Frameworks**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this font 'Kingthings_Trypewriter_2' available in your framework? Have you tried with any custom font which is available internally? I think font you are trying to assign is not found.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to apply fonts that are available internally and if I use this: "label.font=" then it works but by using this: "UILabel.appearance().font=" does not work.

Comment: what 'appearance()' method does?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a specific class and use that custom label or textview for entire framework.

```
  class FrameWorkLabel: UILabel{

var frameWorkFont: UIFont?


private func setupViews(){
    font = frameWorkFont ?? UIFont.frameWorkFont
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupViews()
}

 }

  class FrameWorkTextField: UITextField{

var frameWorkFont: UIFont?

private func setupViews(){
    font = frameWorkFont ?? UIFont.frameWorkFont
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupViews()
}
 }






extension UIFont{
static let frameWorkFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
}
```

Use the instance of label or textfield wherever you want in the project.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label : FrameWorkLabel!
//or
let label1 = FrameWorkLabel()

@IBOutlet weak var textField : FrameWorkTextField!

let textField1 = FrameWorkTextField()
```

Comment: By going this way it will work but still, we need to apply custom class type to each and every UILabels and textFields. and we also need to way to bring font into the framework.